# Websphere - AJAX POST request error

Tags: websphere, http-post, websphere-7

I am using ajax to send data from the client to my server in JSON format and am getting the error message below. Has anybody else managed to resolved this issue ?, because it seems like a lot of people have been getting it.

```
com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest parseParameters SRVE0133E: An error occurred while parsing parameters. {0}
                                 java.io.IOException: SRVE0216E: post body contains less bytes than specified by content-length
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.RequestUtils.parsePostData(RequestUtils.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.parseParameters(SRTServletRequest.java:1887)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletRequest.getParameter(SRTServletRequest.java:1519)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:184)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
```

Comment: It seems like there may be a bug in websphere [https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC56127](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC56127)

Comment: There is also another fix recommended here [http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021045](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=0&uid=swg24021045) but I am alread using websphere version 7.0.0.11 so I shouldnt be getting this problem